# Doubts in prayer

Tags: salat, doubts, takbir

Salamualaykum I’m a person who has doubts probably every day and in that case Ik I maybe should just dismiss those doubts and ignore them but I would like to ask when I was praying and I said the takbir (Allahu Akbar) during prayer I was doubting if I said it right or wrong and maybe I could’ve said it again but because I was praying with someone I wasn’t sure if I could say it again and so I just continued praying. Do I repeat my prayer again or do I just ignore it?

Comment: It's a good practice to ask for forgiveness after each salat for if any ***minor*** mistake or lacking may have been done in praying.